# Understanding managers and self in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to know how do managers work in Django. Let's use the following example (from The Definitive Guide to Django) as the model:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
  def title_count(self, keyword):
    return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField()
  ...
  objects = BookManager()
```

Given that model, we can use `Book.objects.title_count('django')`. However, I'm not sure about what's going on in the background. When we use `title_count`, `self` refers to the instance `BookManager`, which knows about a method called filter because it's inheriting such a method from the `models.Manager` class, but how does it know that it should use filter in instances produced by the `Book` class?.

I would naively think that title_count needs to do  `Books.objects.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()` internally but it's using explicitly something like `objects.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()` without referring to a particular class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the source code it looks like the manager class has a reference to the model that it is embedded in to: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/manager.py#L106

Comment: Uhm, you're right. It seems a bit mysterious. is this one of those things that we need to accept even if they look a bit odd?

Comment: you can start a discussion on the development list and propose another solution.

Comment: Interesting. I'm just learning Django, but maybe other people share the opinion that this is a bit weird. However, as you said, the important thing is to provide another solution. I'm not sure I have a good one. By the way, thanks for your help.

Comment: you say that naively you would think that it should be Books.objects.filter instead of self.filter. if it was the former then you would have an infinite recursion. I also do not understand many things about django, for example why when I store functions in a template context they get invoked when I retrieve them. There are many things that if approached with more thought and education could be implemented better. pylons project's pyramid is a framework that is promising in this respect.

Comment: Sure. I was saying that Books.objects.filter makes sense from the point of view of the programmer but I know it's not always easy to come up with good ways to implement things and still make sense for everybody. I didn't know about that peculiarity with regard to invoked functions after introducing them in a context. Thanks for the tip with respect to pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

> Managers are accessible only via model classes, rather than from model
>   instances, to enforce a separation between "table-level" operations
>   and "record-level" operations. 
>   The Manager is the main source of
>   QuerySets for a model. It acts as a "root" QuerySet that describes all
>   objects in the model's database table. For example, Blog.objects is
>   the initial QuerySet that contains all Blog objects in the database.

Answer (score 1):

[from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) you can see Django sets an attribute called **model** into the manager instance (i.e. **self.model**).
"Manager methods can access self.model to get the model class to which they’re attached."